# При длинном тексте в html-теге <kbd>.....</kbd> надпись растягивается на всю страницу, а не переносится на новую строку

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, дизайн, html-разметка

Если в сообщении будет очень длинное текстовое выделение, то всё нормально:
`ооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооочееееееееееееенннннннннннннннььььььььььььььььььььььььььь длинное текстовое выделение`

Но при использовании html-тега `<kbd>.....</kbd>` очень длинная надпись на новую строку не переносится.

Скриншот:

[image: баг или не баг?]

Или не скриншот:
<kbd>оооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооччччччччччччччччччччччччччееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееенннннннннннннннььььььььььььььььььььььььььь длинное текстовое выделение</kbd>

Возможно ли это исправить?

Comment: я знаю как это исправить — не писать длинное kbd-подобное нечто. А баг предлагаю постить на MSE. Тут мы с этим поведением отдельно ничего не сделаем.

Comment: Если попытаться открыть ссылку [отсюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259059/339911), то даже хром ломается.

Comment: странно, что это тэг сработал на такой ерунде. Когда я недавно пытался поставить его для какого-то набора букв, он не сработал и я решил, что где-то есть список комбинаций (или регулярка), для которых этот тэг работает, как раз, чтобы не использовали для такой ерунды.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML тег `<kbd>` (от слова keyboard - клавиатура) предназначен для обозначения клавиш <kbd>F</kbd> или комбинаций клавиш <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Esc</kbd>.

Для других целей он просто не предназначен. Следовательно, если использовать тег по назначению, то указанная проблема с разметкой сообщения не возникнет.